# Style syntax for Polygon in KML using PHP DOM object

Tags: php, google-maps, styles, kml, polygon

I am working on an application that will make a KML file with PHP. Typically I have done this with single points and had no or little problem, but for polygons I'm having one heck of a hard time getting them to stylize.

What I am attempting to do is colorize a polygon shape based on a dynamic style from PHP; however, I can't even get a hard-coded style to work first. The structure of the KML is shown after the code sample I'm having problems with.

What should the proper style dom syntax look like if all I want to do is setup a polygon color style and a certain width.

Thanks for your help

Here is the initial code:

```
// Creates the Document.
$dom        = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$kmlfile    = $dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1', 'kml');
$parentnode = $dom->appendChild($kmlfile);
$dfnode     = $dom->createElement('Document');
$documentnode = $parentnode->appendChild($dfnode);

$gpsStyleNode = $dom->createElement('Style');
$gpsStyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'style_gps');
$gpsIconstyleNode = $dom->createElement('IconStyle');
$gpsIconstyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'icon_gps');
$gpsIconstyleNode->setAttribute('scale', '0.6');
$gpsIconstyleNode->setAttribute('color', 'ff0000ff');
$gpsIconNode = $dom->createElement('Icon');
$gpsHref = $dom->createElement('href', 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/cross-hairs.png');
$gpsIconNode->appendChild($gpsHref);

$gpsIconstyleNode->appendChild($gpsIconNode);
$gpsStyleNode->appendChild($gpsIconstyleNode);

$gpslinetyleNode = $dom->createElement('PolyStyle');
$gpsStyleNode->appendChild($gpslinetyleNode);   
$gpslinetyleNode->setAttribute('id', 'Icon_gps2');          
$gpslinetyleNode->setAttribute('color', 'ff0000ff');
$gpslinetyleNode->setAttribute('width', '20');

$documentnode->appendChild($gpsStyleNode);
```

KML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Placemark id="12">
<name>PolygonName</name>
<description>test</description>
<styleUrl>Icon_gps2</styleUrl>
<Polygon>
<extrude>1</extrude>
<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
(Dynamic Coords pulled from DB in proper format)
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

EDIT to add Polygon Code

```
$placeobject = $dom->createElement('Placemark');
$placeNode = $nDoc->appendChild($placeobject);          
$placeobject->setAttribute('id',$tmpid);

$placename = $dom->createElement('name','PolygonName');
$placeNode->appendChild($placename);                

$placedesc = $dom->createElement('description', 'test');
$placeNode->appendChild($placedesc);

$stylenode =$dom->createElement('styleUrl','line_gps');
$placeNode->appendChild($stylenode);

$linenode = $dom->createElement('Polygon');
$placeNode->appendChild($linenode);

$lineextrude = $dom->createElement('extrude', '1');
$linenode->appendChild($lineextrude);

$linealtitude = $dom->createElement('altitudeMode', 'relativeToGround');
$linenode->appendChild($linealtitude);                  

$outerboundnode = $dom->createElement('outerBoundaryIs');
$linenode = $linenode->appendChild($outerboundnode);

$ringtype =$dom->createElement('LinearRing');
$linenode = $linenode->appendChild($ringtype);

$coordnode = $dom->createElement('coordinates',$locationstring);
$ringtype->appendChild($coordnode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are setting attributes(color,scale,width) which are expected as elements.

Furthermore width applies to LineStyle and not to PolyStyle

```
$dom        = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$nKml        = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1', 'kml'));
$nDoc        = $nKml->appendChild($dom->createElement('Document'));

$idSuffix='_gps';

//Style
$nStyle      = $nDoc->appendChild($dom->createElement('Style'));
$nStyle->setAttribute('id', 'style'.$idSuffix);

  //IconStyle
  $nIconStyle      = $nStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('IconStyle'));
  $nIconStyle->setAttribute('id', 'icon'.$idSuffix);
    //color
    $nIconStyleColor=$nIconStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('color'));
    $nIconStyleColor->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('ff0000ff'));
    //Icon
    $nIconStyleIcon=$nIconStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('Icon'));
      //href
      $nIconStyleHref=$nIconStyleIcon->appendChild($dom->createElement('href'));
      $nIconStyleHref->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('http://maps.google.com/../cross-hairs.png'));

  //PolyStyle
  $nPolyStyle      = $nStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('PolyStyle'));
  $nPolyStyle->setAttribute('id', 'poly'.$idSuffix);
    //color
    $nPolyStyleColor=$nPolyStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('color'));
    $nPolyStyleColor->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('ff0000ff'));

  //LineStyle
  $nLineStyle      = $nStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('LineStyle'));
  $nLineStyle->setAttribute('id', 'line'.$idSuffix);
    //width
    $nLineStyleWidth=$nLineStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('width'));
    $nLineStyleWidth->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('20'));
    $nLineStyleColor=$nLineStyle->appendChild($dom->createElement('color'));
    $nLineStyleColor->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('ff0000ff'));
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
  <Document>
    <Style id="style_gps">
      <IconStyle id="icon_gps">
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/../cross-hairs.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <PolyStyle id="poly_gps">
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
      </PolyStyle>
      <LineStyle id="line_gps">
        <width>20</width>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
      </LineStyle>
    </Style>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: That looks really good. The script will validate, but the KML file does not have the style in it; I clearly am not building the polygon shape correctly although it does work. I have updated the OP with the code I use to create the Polygon nodes. It works, but it wont style. – Erick Dahl 9 mins ago

Comment: Ahah, you reference the style id not the poly_gps.  Playing with settings to see if I can get it working how I want.